# Using move semantics to push a base class instance into a child class instance

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have an instantiated `Base b`. `Foo` is a child class of `Base`.

What I want to do is to have the constructor for a `Foo`

```
class Foo : public Base
{
    Foo(Base b, T otherArg) : Base(b)
    {
        /*ToDo - do something with otherArg*/
    }
}
```

*move* the 'b' instance to the instance of `Foo` being constructed. If the construction of `Foo` fails (e.g. in my `/*ToDo step*/`) then `b` should not be moved.

Can I do this in C++11? (I cannot afford to take a deep copy). Does the constructor prototype need to be `Foo(Base&& b, T otherArg)`?

Comment: Can you do a second swap in the event of an exception?

Comment: If an exception is thrown in `Foo` construction then any moving of `b` needs to be reversed out.

Comment: What is the use of this? Why move base, and not construct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can :

- Declare a move constructor for the `Base` class so rvalues are accepted
- Move the base argument with [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Base
{
    public:

    Base() {}

    Base(Base&& b) { std::cout << "Move ctr"; }  
};

class Foo : public Base
{
    public:

    Foo(Base&& b, double otherArg) : Base(std::move(b))
    {
       // ...
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo(Base(), 2.0);
}
```

Or

```
int main()
{
    Base b;
    Foo(std::move(b), 2.0);
}
```

Note:

- As for the rollback in case of an exception, you can still save the state of `b` in `Base(Base&& b)` (before doing anything with it, of course), and restore it through a `rollback_move` member function in case of an exception in the `Foo` constructor.

**[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31c51d1eab4133d4)**

Comment: That ignores the question's "construction of `Foo` fails (e.g. in my `/*ToDo step*/`)"...

Comment: Presumably I can move it back if the constructor to `Foo` fails (big try catch block around the whole constructor including base member initialisation).

Comment: @YogiBear before I delete, if you have a failure, then what ? You want to call a base ctor without moving ?

Comment: If I have a failure then the `b` instance in `main` should be left exactly as it was before the `Foo` construction was attempted.

Comment: @YogiBear: yes, you'll need a big try catch, but you also need to know whether the original move construction happened or not so if you have any way for that or any earlier-base construction to fail then you'll need e.g. some sentinel value in the successfully moved-from `Base` or extra member variables around the `Base` construction that track progress and are consulted when deciding whether to `swap` back.

Comment: @YogiBear I added a note to reflect that, you basically can implement  a rollback pattern of some form and/or take the approach of TonyD

Answer (score 0):

Delegating contructors allow us to perform manipulation of arguments, before performing any actual construction.

```
class Foo: public Base {
public:
    // note reference parameter
    Foo(Base&& b, T arg)
        // if do_something fails with an exception here,
        // nothing happens to b since we're just initializing
        // references without touching any object
        : Foo(std::move(b), do_something(arg))
    {}

private:
    Foo(Base&& b, final_arg arg)
        // move construction will only happen here once we
        // have examined the original argument to our satisfaction
        : Base(std::move(b))
    {}
};
```

Be *very* careful when examining an argument. You may feel the need to do something like:

```
Bar(Arg arg)
    : Bar(inspect_argument(arg, this->qux))
{}
```

Using `*this` while the object is under construction is ill-advised. Make sure you know what you are doing.